# Make the screen always be off when having a call

Tags: iphone

Very often when I'm talking on the phone, the screen turns on and my chin and ear presses all the buttons. Often this starts facetime, turn off the sound, and is just very annoying. Is there any way to make the screen always be off when I'm talking? I'm using a regular iPhone 6.

Comment: Comments are not for discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28901/discussion-on-question-by-loovjo-make-the-screen-always-be-off-when-having-a-cal). Focus on improving the question with comments

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me like a bad ambient light sensor and/or the proximity sensor. Both are a part of the front facing camera assembly, and you **cannot** buy them separately.

It should be covered under warranty, but if it's a result of a drop or water damage, then it's not covered under the standard warranty and you may have to have it repaired, either by yourself or a pro.

If you feel comfortable with the repair, here are some tips:

- When removing the digitizer assembly (touchscreen) with a suction cup, take extra care to avoid severing the digitizer and LCD cables.
- If you damage the home button or its cable, then TouchID will no longer work.
- Here's the [guide](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iPhone+6+Front+Facing+Camera+and+Sensor+Cable+Replacement/31672)

Of course, you could always take it to a pro, just be prepared to pay likely $100+, unfortunately. Maybe even $150+, depending on where you go.

If it's not under warranty, though, wait until the iPhone 6S comes out in less than a couple of weeks, as once the iPhone 6 is no longer the newest, parts and repair costs should be lower.

Comment: As I noted in a question comment, as of today all iPhone 6 are still under warranty, call or visit Apple ASAP.  My thinking is that if OP has experience with iPhone repair, then they wouldn't have asked this question.

Comment: Surely you mean the proximity sensor RedEagle2000, not the ambient light sensor.

Comment: @rewozz No, put your finger over the ambient light sensor on your iPhone during a phone call and the screen will turn off, take it away and the screen will turn back on. It doesn't really matter, I guess, as both come on the same part: the front-facing camera assembly.

Comment: According to the [Case Design Guidelines for Apple Devices](https://developer.apple.com/resources/cases/Case-Design-Guidelines.pdf) - [page 16](http://i.imgur.com/gZJ5Tdc.png) the ALS and proximity sensor are not the same thing. Also this: http://ipod.about.com/od/ipodiphonehardwareterms/qt/iphone-sensors.htm

Comment: @rewozz I never said that they are same, they aren't. I just said it didn't really matter which one did what as far as this question goes, as the user in the OP would just have to have the front-facing camera assembly replaced, no matter which one does what. In short, both sensors are very different, but are included in the same camera assembly.

Comment: You should be specific with what is faulty and edit your answer, it's not the ambient light sensor that is broken; it's the proximity sensor inside the assembly. The repair procedure has nothing to do with it. The ambient light sensor could be working just fine doing its thing.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might have a faulty proximity sensor or a case/screen protector that's blocking it.

Either way, there is no solution unless you jailbreak the device.

I suggest going to Apple and have them look at it.

Comment: "There is no solution unless you jailbreak" is incorrect.  You in fact offer another solution (go to apple).  Perhaps what you meant to say is "there are no proximity sensor adjustments available unless you jailbreak the phone."

Comment: The question asked was "Is there any way to make the screen always be off when I'm talking? ". We cannot assume the sensor is broken, if it isn't and the user still experiences the problem he'll have to jailbreak it. There is no guarantee Apple can solve this. The statement is therefore true.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to get the sensors repaired or change how you hold the phone, simply lock the phone once you have accepted the call.

Now the large problem of face touches is mitigated by the lock screen.

Some people either have large ear cavities or don't hold the phone stable or close enough for the sensors to know it is by your face. This locking works and you don't need to use earbuds or other remotes to avoid premature hang up, adding a contact, dialing sounds, etc...

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar issues after an update.  I fixed it by turning off the night sensor.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem. It appears to be fixed, oddly, after I opened the camera app and used the front facing camera in the dark making the flash work on manual and then auto. I'm not sure if it was not talking to the camera or what the problem was but sometimes its the easiest things that fix it.

Answer (score 0):

To check the proximity sensor, you can use Device Doctor (https://itunes.apple.com/vn/app/device-doctor/id1178246735?mt=8). Beside proximity you can check the other functions as well. Good luck

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions

Answer (score 0):

another thing that you should try is turning off the "raise to wake" button under the heading "Display & Brightness" 
This will stop the phone from activating whilst it is moving around, especially if you are using the headphone and you put the phone in your pocket whilst you speak.

Answer (score 0):

another cheap and easy partial fix (at least for the FaceTime part when away from home) is to go into Settings > Cellular and turn off Cellular for FaceTime (in the list of apps at the bottom). My wife has this problem and 99% of the time it's FaceTime that her cheek hits and it's always away from home/wifi.

Answer (score 0):

Press the Home and Power button together for 5 seconds. Then restart your phone after few seconds. I hope it will solve the problem. Mine had the same issue and it is resolved.